# How do I add a cooldown message to my code?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def nuke(ctx, amount=500):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
    await ctx.send(f'Channel has been Nuked!')


@nuke.error
async def nuke_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permissions to use this command!')
```

Just wondering how to add a cooldown message to this, saying: "You must wait 60 seconds before you can use this command again!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```py
if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    await ctx.send("You must wait 60 seconds before you can use this command again!")
```

in `nuke_error` function. This will be work.

Comment: If this works, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to send the error and how many seconds are remaining.

```
@nuke.error
async def nuke_cooldown(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(error)
```